# Android MediaRecorder not working - media server died / Error 100

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I'm trying to follow the MediaRecorder code samples here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

in an attempt and build a video recorder, but while running the code, whenever I attempt to record, I get a "media server died" warning accompanied by "Camera server died", "ICamera died", "msgType = 1", and finally the dreaded "Error 100".

I did a bunch of research and seemed to find a bunch of other people with similar issues, but none of their experienced helped me solve my issue.

My code is fully available here:

https://github.com/loisaidasam/sam-video/

I'm running a T-Mobile G2 on Android 2.3.4

I've been banging my head against a wall for four hours now, so any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the logcat from when you try to record; it's hard to tell what's going on from just your summary of the errors.

Comment: https://raw.github.com/loisaidasam/sam-video/master/failure-logcat.txt

Comment: @LoisaidaSamSandberg I know it's been 10 years, but did you find a solution?